# Does one have to return the specific bills that one stole?

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, money, gezel-stealing

If one stole a hundred dollars in regular cash (e.g. no rare bill editions), and still has those bills, does he have to return those particular bills or can he return any hundred dollars?

Answer (score 6):

It may depend on the condition of the bills when he stole them and when he's repaying the theft. [Shulchan Aruch, Choshen Mishpat 360:7](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14400&st=&pgnum=468) (from Bava Kamma 96b) states:

> הגוזל מעות ישנות ושיפן וחידשן לא קנה שהרי מתיישנין וחוזרים כשהיו. גזל מעות חדשים וישנן קנה שאם יחדשם פנים חדשות הם
>
> If one steals old coins, and polishes them to make them appear new, he hasn't acquired them [i.e., he needs to return the actual coins], because when they become old again they will look just like they did before [and the halachic principle is that only an irreversible change makes the object become the property of the thief]. But if he stole new coins and aged them, he has acquired them [and need return only their value], because even if he makes them look new again, it is [considered] a new "face" [entity].

Needless to say, if the coins are in the same condition as when he stole them, then there has been no change that would make them become his property.

Presumably, then, the same considerations would apply to bills.

Comment: "Presumably, then, the same considerations would apply to bills." -- Not necessarily. One could argue that coins, at least in the times of the *gemara*, depreciated in value when they became aged. Not so with bills nowadays; no matter how old it is, every store must accept it, or at least the bank certainly will.

Comment: I agree with @jake, and am writing to comment that (not only bills but) even *coins* now may well not have the same rules as coins earlier (and perhaps still in some places), since they lack intrinsic value and have only official face value. Nice find, R' Alex, but WADR I don't think it's relevant.

Comment: @jake: if anything, then, according to your logic, that would mean that one always must return the bills, because there has been no significant shinui.

Comment: @msh210: same thing. Indeed, then, this would mean that this particular halachah is even more relevant: coins or bills must always be returned if they are still in the thief's possession. That said, I'm not sure that jake's and your distinction between olden days and today is valid; the real question is whether indeed old coins (that were still full weight, just used) had less value back then. I'll have to research further.

Comment: @Alex IIRC a distinction is made cuz money in their day had intrinsic value (the coin was actually 1 g of gold) while today its more along the lines of a shetar (it represents 1 g of gold)

Comment: @هه: true, and I'm not disputing that point; we know throughout Shas that when coins became underweight (from use) their value decreased. But the Gemara here is talking about new coins vs. שחימי (Rashi: black; Aruch: red), where there's no change in weight, just color; I'm dubious that this would have changed their monetary value even under a gold or silver standard.

Comment: Rema 360:6 (citing Tur) says that the kind of "change" that allows the thief to acquire the stolen object is only where the object thereby gains a new name (such as where he stole wood and turned it into a piece of furniture) - but not necessarily does that mean that there was a change in value. (continued)

Comment: So in the Gemara's case, they're called "coins" either way, and the difference is just in the attached adjective; whether this caused a change in value, I don't know. Today, too, while indeed a $100 bill is a $100 bill, and is worth the same no matter its condition - we do still speak of "crisp" bills vs. "worn" ones. (And arguably, there is a slight difference: some people prefer the former; and vending machines, ATMs, etc., will accept them more easily.)

Comment: @jake great point. With the legal concept of "Legal Tender", one could approach the IRS (US Federal tax agency) and offer them as a tax payment a worn and frayed $100 bill stained with ten years of sweat, ketchup, motor oil, and snot and they would be required to accept it at full value. They might need to call the Hazmat team to decontaminate it, but it would still be worth $100.